# Can I listen to Fitness+ episodes with Bluetooth headphones paired to iPhone instead of watch?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, apple-watch, fitness+

I have an iPhone 13 and Apple Watch 8 and recently started the 3-month free trial for Fitness+. It has these "episodes" and I tried listening to a 34-minute "walk" episode. However, in order to listen to the episode, my watch asked me to pair Bluetooth headphones with it. My Bluetooth headphones are already paired to my iPhone since that's how I listen to all my podcasts and such.

This seems kind of silly to me: my watch only has WiFi, so when I'm walking outside, it actually gets the "episode" audio data from my iPhone anyways, and yet I still need to pair my headphones to the *watch* instead of the phone?

What I really would like to do is to just *keep* the headphone paired to the phone and *not* pair it to the watch, and listen to the episode *that* way, while my watch just measures my heart rate, etc. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I may be missing something here as I do not have an Apple Watch but, can't you pair it to *both* and just switch between them as needed. I do this with Macs, iPhones and TVs in my house and it works fine.

Comment: @SteveChambers It's super annoying to do this, since the wrong devices grab focus whenever they play audio. I don't know what you're experience is like, but I never pair my bluetooth headphones with my Mac or TV because of this - I use an AirFly dongle for those devices. I do pair with the watch, but frankly I'm not sure it's worth it because it interferes with Siri (takes forever to initiate) and I listen from my phone most of the time anyways